# Vertical lines in the projective plane $P^2$

Tags: elliptic-curves, projective-geometry, projective-space

How do you get that two vertical lines in $P^2$ intersect at $(0 : 1 : 0)$ or how do you calculate it?

If we look at two parallel lines, their point of intersection is at $(1 : s : 0)$ with s as the slope of the two parallel lines. As s approaches infinity with vertical lines, why is there a shift from $1$ to $0$ in the x-coordinate as one might have guessed $(1 :  \infty  : 0)$ as the result instead?

Also: is there any way to visualize this?

(I am especially interested because of Elliptic Curves)

Comment: What kind of thing is "inf" here?

Comment: Edited, meant infinity. It is just a naive guess as the slope of two vertical lines is infinite / approaches infinity.

Comment: I was afraid you might mean that :-(

Comment: Maybe it kind of makes sense: the coordinates $(a : b : c)$ denote the ratio between two points (since $(a : b : c) = (\lambda a : \lambda b : \lambda c)$). So if the ratio is $1 : \infty$ this kind of denotes that it approaches $0$ which is $\frac{0}{1}$ and thus $(0 : 1 : 0)$. Is this maybe some kind of valid argument?

Comment: The whole point about homogeneous coordinates that it avoids one having to witter about "infinity".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In standard coordinate geometry, a "vertical" line has equation of the form
$x=a$. The homogeneous form of this is $X=aZ$. This line contains the point
$(X:Y:Z)=(0:1:0)$ in the projective plane, no matter what $a$ is. So all "vertical"
lines meet at $(0:1:0)$.